# Create an IUserType for a class that has an Id

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I hava a `Country` class that has lots of properties, one of them is `Id`. It has a static method `GetById` which returns an instance with that Id.

Now each User has a property `Country` of the type `Country`. I only want to store the Id. When loading an item from the `User` table, the constructor of `Country` should not be called, instead `GetById` should be called.

I also want the User to have an actual reference to the `Country` instance, not a private `countryId` and a public property that calls `GetById`.

I figured that I need to make a `CountryType` that implements [`IUserType`](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-custom), but I don't know how to implement all of its methods, especially `NullSafeGet`.

Is implementing `IUserType` the best way to do this and how would I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement `IUserType` with the help of [this tutorial](http://darrell.mozingo.net/2009/02/10/generic-nhibernate-user-type-base-class/). I only needed to implement the abstract base class provided in the tutorial.

Comment: I'm not allowed to accept this answer, but I don't need any further help with the question.